# Break or continue loop within function calls

Tags: javascript, performance, code-complexity

My question is: How can I trigger a `break;` or `continue;` for a loop through a function that gets called? The thing is, I do not want to nest all possible conditions within a loop to avoid code complexity. I was thinking about some pseudo example:

```
var someObjects = [...] //array with some js objects    

for (var i = 0; i < someObjects.length; i++) {
  var element = someObjects[i];
  doSomething(element);
}

function doSomething(object) {
  //some code here
  if (somethingIsDefined) {
    doSomethingElse(object);
  }
}

function doSomethingElse(anotherObject) {
  //some more code here
  if (somethingMatches) {
    //here i would like to break the most upper loop
  }
}

//someObjects will be processed
```

I know that it would be possible to introduce for example a boolean variable and check within the loop if it is true or false and depending on that, `break;` or `continue;`.
But this - even if it is just one line - would increase the nesting. Do you see any possible solutions?

Comment: You could set a global boolean equal to false, set it equal to true in your function, and check each iteration if the boolean is true.

Comment: you can try moving the iterator outside of the for loop and when the `somethingMatches`, set that to `someObjects.length` so that it moves out of the loop..(just a thought, never did so)

Comment: @AppleCrazy Exactly, but as I mentioned that would increase the nesting within the for loop. I know that I could do this but I wanted to ask if there is a way to avoid nesting.

Comment: @gkb Oh, very good observation. I did not think about that. This could solve it actually. Besides the fact that I would have to pass it as a param if the functions are not within the same context or namespace.

Comment: Yes, It requires to be a global variable but within that namespace or context..to avoid sending it as a parameter..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Underscore library](http://underscorejs.org), which I recommend, you could write the following:

```
_.any(someObjects, doSomething);

function doSomething(object) {
  //some code here
  return somethingIsDefined &&
    doSomethingElse(object);
}

function doSomethingElse(anotherObject) {
  //some more code here
  return  somethingMatches;
}
```